# How to check whether an environment variable is read only or R+W?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

How to check whether an environment variable is read only or R+W on linux system?

As an example BASH_VERSINFO is readonly. do i need to check manual? 
Any other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that makes variables read-only is `readonly`, e.g. `readonly FOO=bar`.

If you call it without arguments, it prints all readonly variables. Check if yours is in there. For me, the following command reduces output to the variable names, one per line:

```
readonly | cut -d= -f1 | cut -d' ' -f3
```